# WP_LOCALIZE_SCRIPT doesn't work

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, ajax, wp-localize-script, customization

I am creating AJAX loading and need to use WP_LOCALIZE_SCRIPT but cannot make it work.

Here is my code. I place it in functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'page_data');
$gallery_js_data_array = array(
            'maxPages' => '$gallery_max_load = $gallery->max_num_pages;',
            'curPage' => '1'
);
wp_localize_script( 'script', 'glr_dt', $gallery_js_data_array);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the correct handle:

```
wp_localize_script('page_data', 'glr_dt', $gallery_js_data_array);
```

**// Edit**
Your code is also wrong. What do you want to do in this line:

```
'maxPages' => '$gallery_max_load = $gallery->max_num_pages;'
```

You are assigning a string to `maxPages`.

I guess you want it that way (or similar):

```
'maxPages' => $gallery->max_num_pages,
```

Now, you can access the var in your JS as `glr_dt.maxPages`

Comment: I am sorry I paste the code with wrong handle. It is not working with PAGE_DATA handle !

Answer (score 1):

Try making the original script a dependency

```
  <?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, 'original_script_handle'); ?>
```

Comment: The only way I found to run it is if i give path to enqueue a file

wp_enqueue_script( 'page_data',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gallery.js', array('jquery'));

But I don't want to enqueue any file. I want just to have the those 2 vars